# Kivy UrlRequest

Tags: python, kivy

My API works fine and I see a `200` status when I test it using Postman. However I'm trying to access it using a Kivy application but I'm seeing a `400` response from the server after some waiting or quitting the app.  By the way when testing with Postman I specify header as `Content-Type: application/json` and in body I see my parameters

```
{
    "search_text": "Hello",
    "num_results": 1
}
```

being sent as `raw` data. 
**My code**

```
def search(self, search_text):
        header = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        req = UrlRequest('http://127.0.0.1:5000/search',req_body={"search_text": search_text,"num_results": 1},on_success=Test.got_json,req_headers=header)
        print("Search method called")


@staticmethod
def got_json(req,result):
        print(result)
```

Kivy docs say that you don't have to specify a method as this would send a `POST` request so I've not specified that here
**Edit:** The code for the server is kind of irrelevant for my issue here so I've removed it

Comment: You must provide a [mcve] if you want us to help you, and in your case we need you to show how you have implemented the server, otherwise your question falls on the off-topic: **Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.** [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for the feedback. I guess the title for my question was quite misleading. My question was rather only concerned with the `UrlRequest` function of Kivy and if I'm using it correctly and not regarding the debugging for my server side code. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @eyllanesc at the moment my Flask server does nothing more than spit out a 'Hello' message when received a request

Comment: I understand your question clearly, but being a self that you implement and we can not access or test could have errors that cause that error, my idea is to reproduce the most accurate way, I would ignore that request if you show that the same error occurs with other servers, have you tried with another type of server, another type of order, for example GET, ect ?.

Comment: A Flask server that implements a Hello World does not have many files, so I think you can show what you have implemented.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry for late response. Thats pretty much it

Comment: @eyllanesc if thats helpful, in jquery I sent a Post request with only the parameters and I did see a response. so maybe some encoding issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UrlRequest` should be passed a `str` object as request body. You can serialize the request dictionary as a string object by dumping it. Pass this dumped dictionary as the request body to `UrlRequest`.

```
import json

req_body=json.dumps({'search_text': search_text, 'num_results': 1})
req = UrlRequest(
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/search',
         req_body=req_body,
         on_success=Test.got_json,
         req_headers=header)
```

Comment: Thank you @DipanshuJuneja . :)

Answer (score 2):

req_body is a string parameter, might be a bit confusing as req_headers is a dict. You can use:

```
req_body=json.dumps({"search_text": search_text,"num_results": 1})
```